# Can connect to Azure SQL using ADFv2 connection using Service Principal but not through SSMS

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, ssms, azure-data-factory

I am able to connect to a specific Azure SQL Database using ADFv2 connection with Authentication Type as Service Principal. But I am trying to figure out how to connect to the same Azure SQL DB using SSMS using the service principal. If I just try to use the service principal ID as 'Login' and its secret as Password in the SSMS login screen (Authentication: SQL Server Authentication), it doesn't work. There is no option in SSMS to select service principal authentication. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not connect to the Azure SQL database with Service Principal in SSMS. As you found that there is no option can support this.

I found a Azure Support blog that give the answer for you:

**Just to mention that there it not possible to use SQL SERVER Management Studio to connect using Service Principals and you need to use a C# to be able to connect using it.**

Reference: [Lesson Learned #49: Does Azure SQL Database support Azure Active Directory connections using Service Principals?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Database-Support-Blog/Lesson-Learned-49-Does-Azure-SQL-Database-support-Azure-Active/ba-p/369055)

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any non-coding alternative available for accessing using service principal? Like any other tool that can be configured for access

Comment: that code shown in the link did not work -- I got the error:- GetSqlQuery : Cannot open server 'mysqlservermasked' requested by the login. Client with IP address 
'myipaddress' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure 
Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for 
this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.

Comment: like the error message said, did you add the client ip '73.181.147.33' to the Azure SQL server firewall  setting? Follow this document [Create a server-level IP firewall rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule)

Comment: if you don't set the firewall role, you can not access the Azure SQL database.

Comment: this is the whole point -- I can access using ADFv2 purely using service principal -- but if a business user just wants to have a look at the data how can he do so in this case , he can't obviously create ADFv2 pipeline just to 'see' the data. And I don't have direct access to the azure sql server resource in question to be able to set firewall rule -- all I have is a service principal through which I am granted access

Comment: Yeah, that's the real question.  I don't know if there is a tool has the available for accessing using service principal (I also didn't find it), what I can only tell you is that SSMS doesn't support login with Service Principal.  As you said, you can not set the firewall and only have the service principal, I'm afraid to tell you  we can not achieve that, at least for now. You can mark it is as the answer, or waiting for others  can give better suggestions, thank you.